# Magento Multi Site on Amazon Cloud

Tags: php, magento, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to migrate our Magento to Amazon Cloud.

Currently we have this setup:

```
www.xyz.com (/var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/httpdocs)
```

This is where Magento is setup:

```
www.abc.com
```

This is where our Wordpress is setup:

```
www.abc.com/store/
```

This is a multi store setup to use the code in `xyz.com` with `index.php` calling the Magento app.

Initially, I was thinking of using 1 EC2 instance for Magento and another EC2 instances for the Wordpress. Then I would setup 2 Elastic IPs to the 2 instances and then point `abc.com` and `xyz.com` to their EIPs accordingly.

However, I can't think of a way for the `/store/` folder under `abc.com` to use the same source code for Magento.

Could anyone advise?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019328/sub-directory-to-a-different-server

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure about your needs but I would recommend to have store.abc.com as subdomain - this way you can link xyz.com and store.abc.com to the same folder and keep abc.com to the main wordpress folder. But again need to look deeper into the setup. we just transferred one of the store to amazon AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is a Proxy. Everything else (Like mod_rewrite / Alias) will do a header redirect, and expose the target address to the user.

However, Apache's proxying doesn't seem to be that complicated. The most basic example is

ProxyPass /mirror/foo/ http://backend.example.com/

Note that a proxy will of course double your traffic, because every byte requested will have to be fetched from the remote machine.

Source: [Sub Directory to a different server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019328/sub-directory-to-a-different-server)