# apache: redirect some site from dedicated mutual hosting to private home server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, nas

I plan to buy a domain name (let's say domain-example.com) and some hosting solution, (e.g.,  at  Gandi or OVH). 
I would like to have the following configuration:

- the domain-example.com points to the Gandi server. (IP 5.6.7.8)
- on the gandi server , put a web page with curriculum, papers, etc , so it is always accessible: call it "research"
- on a private server in my home (I have a static IP: 1.2.3.4), i have "owncloud", "multicraft", etc.

Is it possible to obtain the following configuration with apache on the gandi server:

- domain-example.com/research gives the web site hosted by Gandi
- domain-example.com/owncloud redirect to 1.2.3.4/owncloud, hosted on my own server.

Currently my home server is properly configured, I can access 1.2.3.4/owncloud from outside without any problem, my question is really how to configure apache on the gandi server.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a **static** or a **dynamic IP address** ? *If static - yes it is possible by several ways, I think htaccess/mod_rewrite is the easiest. If not, I suggest afraid.org, register a subdomain, put a frameset on the public server and point it to that subdomain.*

Comment: I have a static IP. I came across htaccess/mod_rewrite in my research, but I could not find a clear example...

Comment: I know it is easily possible to proxy `yourdomain.com/folder` to `1.2.3.4/owncloud`, I just don't know the exact rule. You should tag the question `.htaccess` and/or `mod_rewrite` to attract people who can help regarding this.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019328/sub-directory-to-a-different-server